# Email notification on new azure multi-stage pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

I need an email notification on approval check in the new azure devops multi-stage pipeline to the approver. How do I go about setting that up?

Comment: Hi,user3231744 Is the information I provided helpful to you? If you have any question ,please kindly let me know.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! Was hoping for another answer, but now I know and can stop looking for the possibility and can simply wait for the features to evolve. (I have cast a vote in the provided link.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Email notification on new azure multi-stage pipeline

For this issue, it is currently not achievable in azure devops . This issue has been reported as a bug in our Developer Community forum :[Notification not working when using approval checks in YAML pipelines](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/697513/notification-not-working-when-using-approval-check.html)

This is a known gap with multi-stage pipelines that product group are working on. It is now under consideration.You can vote and comment in that case to increase the priority of the issue. If there is any progress, you will be notified in time.